# Как вернуть config npm в рабочую папку?

Tags: cmd, npm

Не работал gulp, нашел в сети исправление ошибки с помощью команды

```
npm config set prefix
```

и после него не работает npm вообще, из за того, что указал не верный адрес папки.

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program
> Files\Git\usr\local'

Как починить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Запустите cmd от имени администратора
- Запустите `npm config edit` (вы получите редактор блокнота)
- Измените prefix переменную на `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\npm`